# Calling a subclassed virtual method from a base class method

Tags: c++, methods, polymorphism, virtual

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void
        doSomething(void)
    {}

    void
        doStuff(void)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void
        doSomething(void)
    {
        // do some stuff here
    }
};

B * b = new B;
b->doStuff();
```

It gives me Segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong? It should work well in my opinion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're not doing any polymorphism in the code bellow the class definition.

`b->doStuff()` should call the method of `B` class. If you want to inside B call `A-> doSomething` you can use `A:: doSomething`

Comment: B hasn't got a doStuff member - so A::doStuff will be called.

Comment: He's calling the non-polymorphic `doStuff`, whose implementation invokes the polymorphic `doSomething`.

Comment: I am calling `doStuff()` which is declared in `B` class and called from `A` class.

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled the name, I intended to say `doSomething`

Comment: Now I understand what ChrisW ment. Yes, I'm calling the non-polymorphic `doStuff`, whose implementation invokes the polymorphic `doSomething`, but it occurs with Segmentation fault in my code.

Answer (score 5):

After I corrected the syntax errors and added a main() function, it compiled and executed for me with no problems. Try posting the REAL code that causes the problem, and rethink your code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the `:` after `class A` and `public A`...

Comment: My bad. But it wasn't the problem anyway.